# Don't know how to run ifort after installing parallel studio

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I did a full and successful installation of Intel parallel studio on Ubuntu 18 just so I could compile with ifort.  But now I can't figure out what to do next since the terminal doesn't recognize the ifort command.

Comment: Does https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8840902 help?

Comment: Yes it does thanks